# Unable to resolve module react-native-fbsdk from /Users/username/MyApp/app.js in android

Tags: react-native

I have not found any answer on this type of question. please help me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrJFq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the **react-native-fbsdk** to your package.json in order to npm install the dependency?

You should add some code snippet and a stacktrace of your error that will help people to understand your problem and make it easy to help you!

Comment: I am following this link - https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk#installation

I have added react-native-fbsdk but now getting this error
Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[5,6)] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: Now i have another issue 
when i run this - react-native link react-native-fbsdk
error Failed to get dependency config

Comment: {
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "android": "react-native run-android"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "link": "^0.1.5",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "^0.59.9",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^1.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {

Comment: Maybe you can check if the versions of react and react-native are compatible with the react-native-fbsdk